# Android Shared Preferences betwen Activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've on Activity A the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("nome", nome.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

I've on Activity B the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
String a = sharedPreferences.getString("nome", "");
nomeMediador.setText(a); //TextBox
```

Can anyone tell why it's not showing (the value saved on Activity A) on Activity B?

Comment: once check whether the string 'a' contains the value or not.

Comment: how and when do you start activity B? Is it happening after the commit in activity A?

Comment: nomeMediador is your text view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below code

Activity A

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("nome", nome.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Activity B

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String a = sharedPreferences.getString("nome", "");
nomeMediador.setText(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

its better use getter and setter with the help of string.xml file, you will never get this kind of problem. for that matter you may check this blog:

http://sspower3.blogspot.in/2011/11/sharedpreferences-in-eazy-way.html